# Problema con Asynctask que al insertar en base de datos no pasa a la siguiente actividad

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Tengo un formulario de ingreso de un usuario que está conectado a una base de datos MySQL.

El problema es que al realizar la inserción no me pasa a la siguiente actividad. El problema está en `onPostExecute` a mi parecer, ¿alguna idea?

```
private class Asyncinsert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(formularioAsistente.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setTitle("Verificando");
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tUn Momento...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


            url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/asistente/asistenteinsert.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {

            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


// setDoInput y setDoOutput representan el manejo de los mensajes de envío y recepción
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Añado parámetros a la URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("primer_nombre", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("primer_apellido", params[1])
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", params[2])
                    .appendQueryParameter("tipo_asistente", params[3]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Abro conexion para enviar datos
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

// Compruebo si se ha realizado correctamente la conexion

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


// Leo los datos enviados desde el servidor
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


// Paso los datos al método onPostExecute
                return(result.toString());

            }else{

                return("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // este método se ejecutará en el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido: "+email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(formularioAsistente.this,ParticiparEvento.class);
            startActivity(intent);




        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(formularioAsistente.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, intente nuevamente.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {


            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(formularioAsistente.this);
            alertaDeError2.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError2.setMessage("Ha ocurrido un error inesperado. Intente nuevamente.");
            alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError2.create();
            alertaDeError2.show();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @FelizBeeb entra a alguno de los if/else que tienes? y a cual? puedes imprimir el valor de `result` y dejarlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: @FelizBeeb, realiza debug y verifica en  protected void onPostExecute(String result) { que valor tiene "result"-.

Answer (score 0):

No realiza el `Intent` simplemente porque la variable `result` que recibes en `onPostExecute()` no contiene el valor `"true"`.

```
 if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
```

Dentro de doInBackground() revisa aquí:

```
// Paso los datos al método onPostExecute
   return(result.toString());
```

**La única forma que no ejecute el Intent es que  `result` no contiene el valor `"true"`.**

Puedes agregar 2 validaciones, convertir a minúsculas y eliminar espacios, dentro de la variable.

```
 if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true").toLowerCase().trim()) {
```

Comment: Amigo @Elanasys, esto no iria como comentario? ya que no sabemos si efectivamente result trae o no ese valor? Solo como consulta, saludos!

Comment: Hola amigo @sioesi, al llamarse el método onPostExecute() recibe el valor de la variable result, para realizar el intent debe cumplirse:  if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) { yo aseguro que definitivamente result no tiene el valor "true".

Comment: efectivamente, de hecho le pedi si podia dejar impreso el valor que tiene result, de todas formas es una buen consejo eliminar los espacios en blancos y quizas minimizarlas, esperemos haber si nos deja mas info., Saludos :D

Comment: el Error como decian mas arriba es que no recibe un true y efectivamente use unsuccessful, es decir if(!result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) y ahora funciona perfecto, gracias por las ideas !